# Is it possible to remove or move the Gluon Mobile Swatch

Tags: gluon-mobile

The Swatch in a Gluon Mobile app is very "Android-ish" -- most (all?) iOS apps don't have swatches.

So I was wondering if it possible to do one or all of:

1. not have a swatch
2. have the swatch but at the bottom of the app
3. put scene graph nodes in the swatch (this and 1)) means I can put the swatch at the bottom and use it as a tool bar of sorts).

thx
g